# Extracting hyperlinks from selected text in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink, selection

What should be changed in the code (found on [www.extendoffice.com](http://www.extendoffice.com)) to restrict this to the selected part of the text (not to work throughout the whole document).

The code is extracting hyperlinks from one Word doc to another.

```vb
Sub HyperlinksExtract()
    Dim oLink As Hyperlink
    Dim docCurrent As Document 'current document
    Dim docNew As Document 'new document
    Dim rngStory As StoryRanges
    Set docCurrent = ActiveDocument
    Set docNew = Documents.Add
    For Each oLink In docCurrent.Hyperlinks
        oLink.range.Copy
        docNew.Activate
        Selection.Paste
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    Next
     
    Set docNew = Nothing
    Set docCurrent = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Try For Each oLink In Selection.Hyperlinks`, might not work because of `docNew.Activate`. Where in `docNew` are you pasting at?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. With For Each oLink In Selection.Hyperlinks there is new doc opened but empty. I would like to just generate list of those hyperlinks in any form - now it is in new doc but can be in excel too or even in the same document as selected text - just to create the list of those hyperlinks at the end of the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to store the selected hyperlinks in a variable `selectedHyperlinks`.

Furthermore I always try to avoid copy/paste.Therefore I am using the `Hyperlinks.Add` method to insert the links to the new document

```vb
Sub HyperlinksExtract()

    Dim docCurrent As Document
    Dim docNew As Document
    
    Set docNew = Documents.Add
    Dim rgTarget As Range: Set rgTarget = docNew.Range
    
    Dim selectedHyperlinks As Hyperlinks
    Set selectedHyperlinks = Selection.Hyperlinks   '<<< this is where the selected hyperlinks are stored in the variable
    
    Dim oLink As Hyperlink
    
    For Each oLink In selectedHyperlinks 
        rgTarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        docNew.Hyperlinks.Add rgTarget, oLink.Address, oLink.SubAddress, , oLink.TextToDisplay
        rgTarget.Move wdParagraph, 1
        rgTarget.InsertParagraphAfter
    Next
     
End Sub
```